# mysql inner join 3 tables get last record from max date

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables which i would like joined but with some addition to summing certain columns
I need to display every user_id and user name in the database but also joining their corresponding accounts tables with some addition and date based query. Here is an example of what im trying to say.

**Table Users**

```
user_id || user_name || user_dob    
    301 || john doe   ||  1955-01-01    
    312 || Bill Gates || 1976-01-01
```

**Table accounts**

```
 id  || child_id ||          inv_date     || inv_total || inv_funding    
 38  ||   301    ||  2018-05-03 12:56:38  ||    486.5  ||   45.55     
 39  ||   301    ||  2018-08-03 14:56:38  ||    222.5  ||   118.5     
 40  ||   312    ||  2018-04-03 11:56:38  ||    26.23  ||   318.5     
 41  ||   312    ||  2018-05-03 12:56:38  ||    223.22 ||   238.5     
 42  ||   312    ||  2018-06-03 13:56:38  ||    486.5  ||   258.5
```

**Table accounts_balance**

```
id || child_id || balance    
1  ||    301   || 302.00    
2  ||    312   || 43.33
```

The resulting table needs to look like this for every user in Table Users ordered by user_name

```
User Name || Last Invoiced Date || Last Funding Amount || Last Invoice Amount || Total Funding To Date || Total Invoiced To Date || Balance
john doe  || 2018-08-03 14:56:38||      118.5          ||        222.5        ||        164.05         ||        712.00          ||    302.00
```

here is some of my code excuse the c# formating clearly not working well.

```
            invoiceTable.Query = "select  " +
                "(" +
                "max(users.user_id), " +
                "users.user_name, " +
                "max(accounts.inv_date), " +
                "max(accounts.inv_funding) as Last_funding, " +
                "max(accounts.inv_total) as Last_Invoice, " +
                "sum(accounts.inv_funding) as Total_Funding, " +
                "sum(accounts.inv_total) as Total_Invoiced from users " +
                ")" +
                "left join accounts on accounts.child_id = users.user_id group by users.user_name";
```

Comment: There is still a 3rd table account balance needs to be joined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try by using `sub-query`

```
          select t1.*,t2.inv_funding as Last_funding,t2.inv_total as 
          Last_Invoice,ab.balance  from
               (
                select users.user_id, 
                users.user_name, 
                max(accounts.inv_date) as inv_date,
                sum(inv_funding) as Total_Funding,
                sum(inv_total) as Total_Invoiced 
                from users                    
                left join accounts on accounts.child_id = users.user_id
                group by users.user_name,users.user_id 
             ) as t1
         left join accounts t2 on t1.inv_date=t2.inv_date
         left join accounts_balance ab on t1.user_id =ab.user_id
```

Comment: this is nearly right its still missing the balance column which is a separate table called Table accounts_balance

Comment: @daniel just min im going to add it

Comment: I know ive answered with correct . Theres still a mistake the total invoiced to date and total funding to date arent summing or adding up

Comment: I tried summing but im having difficulties would you mind showing me thanks zaynul

Comment: @daniel i have edited answer can you please check now